# So many people to hate, and almost nobody to love

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Could you say please it's the idiom, or this expression doesn't exist in English? Does that expression mean they like to hate and don't like to love?

If that phrase is awkward, could you say please something similar and natural that.

> **So many people to hate, and almost nobody to love.**

Comment: Please say where you found this expression. I'm not aware of it existing as an idiom in English. If it does, it's a very cynical one.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, That's from my online course.

Comment: As @Kate says, it's a very cynical / nihilistic (or perhaps just "ignorant / childish") thing to say in the context of some kind of educational coursework text. So my guess is the course wasn't put together by native Anglophones - in which case if it's a course intended to actually teach *English*, you might want to approach it with caution.

Comment: More positively, perhaps, [***So many women, so little time***](https://www.amazon.com/Women-Little-T-Shirt-saying-sarcastic/dp/B07PLXDFWP) (to make love to all of them! :)

Comment: ...I assume the intended meaning of the cited text is the writer thinks almost everyone except himself is bad (and therefore should be hated). He's bewailing the fact that he can't find any / enough people worthy of his love and affection.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that first phrase not very useful. I have transformed it into this one: **So many things to be interesting, and almost nothing to be fatal.** I hope it sounds good.

Comment: No, neither of your suggestions would sound "good" to most native speakers. The construction I presented above is *relatively* "productive" (there are many written instances of things like [*So much world, so little time*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22so+much+world+so+little+time%22) and [*So much to see and so little time to see it in,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22so+much+to+see+so+little+time%22), for example). But it won't work for all values of X and Y in *So much X [and] so little Y*.

Comment: ...and that's quite apart from the fact that "being interesting" and "being fatal" don't have any useful connection that could be contrasted (whimsically or otherwise).